# Lazy loading using ADO.NET DataReader and Web sockets

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, ado.net

I am trying to implement lazy loading for my application using DataReader and Web sockets.
My aim is to run a 'select all' query which has millions of records, then push the results one by one to the client using web sockets from the data reader.

I understand datareader will fetch only single row at a time (when executing read method), and theoretically there should not be any performance difference between 'select all' and 'select top' queries.

But my ExecuteReader method takes 160 seconds for 'select all' query, and 24 milliseconds for 'select top 1' query. Can somebody explain this behavior ?

Comment: Despite what you think, there is a difference in performance between select all and select top.  Because in your select all statement you need to transfer millions of rows of data to the client, but in select top 1 you only need to transfer 1 row.

Comment: Upload the actual execution plan XML of the select all query to [Paste The Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) and add the link to your question. If there are blocking operators in the plan, it may take some time before rows are available.

Comment: If you have million of records in table then definitely `top 1 *` will be faster then `*`

Comment: @viveknuna Might not be much faster if there is a blocking operator in the plan

Comment: If you are planning on holding a DataReader open for any length of time then you're doing it wrong. This way will cause the server to hold open locks on the rows/tables involved, which is going to be very bad for concurrency. You may want to look at [Keyset Pagination](https://use-the-index-luke.com/no-offset) instead, which is far more efficient. Other than that, we cannot advise without seeing the query, tables, indexes, and most important the query plan which you can share via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan